# Selenium webdriver can't click on a link outside the page

Tags: java, selenium, scroll, click, webdriver

I am having an issue with Selenium WebDriver. I try to click on a link that is outside the window page (you'd need to scroll up to see it). My current code is fairly standard:

```
menuItem = driver.findElement(By.id("MTP"));
menuItem.click();
// I also tried menuItem.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

I know I could scroll up, and it would work in this case. But in a case where you have a long list of items, you don't necessarily know how far you have to scroll down.

Is there any way to click on a link that is not on the visible part of the page (but that would be visible if you scroll)?

As a side note, I'm using Firefox, but I am planning to use IE7/8/9 and Chrome as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm afraid I can't give the source code, as the company I work for doesn't allow it, but I can give the code of the link I want to click on:

```
<div class="submenu">
  <div id="MTP">Link title</div>
</div>
```

The exact same code works when the link is visible, only when it is not does it not work.

Edit2: Actually, oddly enough, it doesn't raise any exception and just goes to the next instruction. So basically, what happens is:

```
menuItem = driver.findElement(By.id("MTP")); // no exception
menuItem.click();  // no exception
//... some code ensuring we got to the next page: timeout reached
driver.findElement(By.id("smLH")).click(); // NoSuchElementException, as we're on the wrong page.
```

Comment: What version of webdriver are you using? I know this has been an issue in earlier versions but its been resolved in later. Try using 2.25 if you are not.

Comment: Also do you have to scroll browser's scroll or some custom scroll for the list on the page?

Comment: I am using version 2.25 already. As for the scroll bar, there is only the browser's scroll in the page. But ideally, I don't want to be using any scrollbar.

Comment: Can you provide some source code of the webpage under test?

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Could you post it?

Comment: Edited my post to answer your questions Arek and JacekM.

Comment: Use PhantomJS instead of Firefox

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is actually possible to scroll automatically to element. Although this is not a good solution in this case (there must be a way to get it working without scrolling) I will post it as a workaround. I hope someone will come up with better idea...

```
public void scrollAndClick(By by)
{
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
   int elementPosition = element.getLocation().getY();
   String js = String.format("window.scroll(0, %s)", elementPosition);
   ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(js);
   element.click();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I posted this same answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035023/selenium-webdriver-cant-click-on-a-link-outside-the-page?lq=1) so this is just a copy and paste.

I once had a combo box that wasn't in view that I needed to expand. What I did was use the Actions builder because the moveToElement() function will automatically scroll the object into view. Then it can be clicked on.

```
WebElement element = panel.findElement(By.className("tabComboBoxButton"));

Actions builder = new Actions(this.driver);

builder.moveToElement(element);
builder.click();
builder.build().perform();
```

(panel is simply a wrapped element in my POM)

Comment: Worked like a charm!  (All methods in uppercase though in C#)

Comment: @Bill, that link goes back to this same question.  I would like to see the issue you meant to link to.  Could you update with the right link please?

Answer (score 13):

Instead of move the scrollbar to the button position, which sometimes it didn't work for me, I send the enter key to the button

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("button"));
element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: Tons of agonized answers, when this sufficient for many cases.. good call.

Comment: I think the real problem is webdriver not able to locate the button.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar problem recently when there was a list of selectable objects in a JS dialog. Sometimes selenium would not select the correct object in the list. So i found this javascript suggestion:

```
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.id("myId"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", target);
Thread.sleep(500); //not sure why the sleep was needed, but it was needed or it wouldnt work :(
target.click();
```

That solved my issue

Answer (score 5):

Hey you can use this for ruby

```
variable.element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Store the element to find in variable

Answer (score 4):

It might be occurring because your header element or the footer element might be blocking the view of the element you want to perform action on. Selenium tries to scroll to the element position when it has to perform some action on the element (I am using Selenium WebDriver v3.4.0).

Here is a workaround -

```
private WebElement scrollToElementByOffset(WebElement element, int offset) {
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + element.getLocation().getX() + "," + (element.getLocation().getY()
            + offset) + ");");

    return element;
}
```

The above function scrolls the view to the element and then scrolls further by the offset you provide. And you can call this method by doing something like -

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("element1"));
scrollToElementByOffset(webElement, -200).click();
```

Now, this is just a workaround. I gladly welcome better solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked like a charm for me:

```
public void click(By by) throws Exception{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    element.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (in c#)-

```
item = driver.findelement(by.....);
item.SendKeys(Keys.LeftControl);
item.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition:
In my case the button was overlapped by another floating button.

Just resizing the browser window solved the problem!

Comment: How can I beat the issue without resize the browser window size ?

Comment: To be honest, this is already some time ago.

What just comes into my mind, but this is a only a guess that needed to be verified by somebody: what if the button is first moved up in the 3D-hirarchy (z-index Property) to the top with a javascript? 
Just an idea. Don't know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I used the method below to solve a similar issue for Selenium Java:

```
public static void scrollToElementByElement(WebElement element) {

    Coordinates coordinates = ((Locatable)element).getCoordinates();
    coordinates.inViewPort();
    coordinates.click(); //if needed

}
```

Then called on the method on my main test class

Answer (score 0):

I have used below method to solve the problem of element not present in the visible area. The code scrolls down the webpage, till selenium operations can be performed on the element. Change the co ordinate of Y-axis and value of i as per requirement.

```
public void scrooling(By ele) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                driver.findElement(ele);
                break;
            } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,400)");
                System.out.println("inside ElementNotVisibleException block");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,400)");
                System.out.println("inside NoSuchElementException block");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Java equivalent, but the easiest way I could solve the issue of "click a link outside the page" is with the use of the `location_once_scrolled_into_view` property of WebElements.

> THIS PROPERTY MAY CHANGE WITHOUT WARNING. Use this to discover where on the screen an element is so that we can click it. This method should cause the element to be scrolled into view.
> Returns the top lefthand corner location on the screen, or zero coordinates if the element is not visible.

It would return the coordinates if you need them, but also it will automatically scroll down the page to show the element.

EX:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//b[text()="Next"]')
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

I was using Python3.11, Selenium 4.