# Selenium click action directs to page other than by Selenium IDE

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a web element using Selenium WebDriver(2.21.0).

When I try driving through the Selenium IDE it works properly but when I try the same set of actions using the Java implementation of Firefox driver- it leads to the wrong page.

**While the code is running and I manually scroll to the desired element, it works.**

I am making sure that the web element is visible and enabled using

```
By by = By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:void(0);')])[26]"); //**Edit:** this is how i  
                                                                       //am getting the locator

WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);


return (element.isEnabled() || element.isDisplayed()) ? element : null;
```

which returns some element but not the one I am expecting.

This looks strange to me as Selenium webdriver mostly scrolls to an element(if not visible on the screen) by itself and does the required interaction.

I have tried some answers like [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035023/selenium-webdriver-cant-click-on-a-link-outside-the-page), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium) with no success.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** here is the IDE's exported code(java/JUnit4/webdriver)

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Bandar {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://e.weibo.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBandar() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/nescafechina");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:void(0);')])[26]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:void(0);')])[12]")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the export in here for what the Selenium IDE is doing?

Comment: Thanks for the response Mr.Curtis! I have pasted Selenium IDE's exported Test case.

Comment: Seems to me that I have to give a better locator than the ones created  by the Selenium IDE. I have tried the XPath locator generated from FirePath and Firebug without any success.

Answer (score 1):

Ishank,

What I have done is gone through and created a test that shows the different kind of asserts that you can use in your testing. They do look a little different from what you are looking at, I feel your main problem is `WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);` because you are not giving it an actual element. The `(by);` section is looking for a string that can be found on the page. Acceptable strings would be; id`("gbfqb");` or xpath`("(//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:void(0);')])[26]");` or even name`("find-button");`.

```
/**
 * Test the main Google page.
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 * 
 */
@Test
public void signUp() throws InterruptedException {

String testId = "TestStack01";

entered(testId);

webDriver.get("www.google.com");
webDriver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
webDriver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("Test");
assertEquals("", webDriver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).getText());

WebElement whatyourlookingfor = webDriver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb"));
assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("gbqfb"));
assertTrue(whatyourlookingfor.isEnabled());
assertTrue(whatyourlookingfor.isDisplayed());
assertFalse(whatyourlookingfor.isSelected());

webDriver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();

leaving(testId);

}
```

I hope that this has helped in getting which element is being returned.

Curtis Miller

Comment: Hey Curtis, thanks for ur time!
I have edited the code snippet, I have been obtaining the 'by' from- By by = By.xpath("(//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:void(0);')])[26]"); so, I hope that the correct Locator goes in driver.findElement(by); ..

Comment: It looks like the javascript in the Xpath is what could be causing the issue. You might want to try something like 'selenium.fireEvent("name=title", "blur"); ' after the javascript action is being performed.