# Multiple Scroll Bars in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scroll the left nav bar (which shows the job list) to the bottom using python, selenium and chromedriver. I tried using:

```
_driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

But nothing happened. I'm new to web automation, please let me know if you need anything.

P.S. [Page source](https://www.google.com/search?q=mba%20jobs&ie=UTF-8&ibp=htl;jobs#fpstate=tldetail)

[image: Page image]

Comment: It is a common issue to scroll inside an HTML element. Check out these answers:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189182/how-to-scroll-a-specific-div-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java
BTW, you don't need to scroll in order to act on an element, if you need to load new list elements you may just execute the specific script/function in your page (to find this function you have to use brower's developer tool).

Comment: Thank you furkanayd. Can you please guide me how to find those particular scripts/functions? The above question link was helpful for me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the last element `job list` in the left nav bar:

```
(//li[contains(@class, 'PaEvOc')])[last()]
```

To achieve scroll to bottom left nav use `.location_once_scrolled_into_view`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//li[contains(@class, 'PaEvOc')])[last()]")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Comment: How did you manage to find 'PaEvOc' ? I tried to inspect that page again, and could not find `PaEvOc` or  `gws-horizon-textlists__li-ed` on that page (I presume this is how people found that last element in the past). I am attempting the same exercise and am also stuck similarly to the original poster