# Element not clickable error for drop down developed using div Tag

Tags: selenium

I am getting Element not clickable error when click on dropdown developed with div tag.

Here the HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-control btn-group ui-multiselect-dropdown ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-valid-schema-form ng-touched" data-role="multiselect" ng-init="open=false" ng-class="{open: open}" autopopulate-to="form" populate-to="form" reload-options="form" schema-name="form" sf-changed="form" schema-validate="form" auto-tab-field="" ng-model="model['notifications']['preferredMedium']" tabindex="15" ng-disabled="form.readonly || (form.enabled && !evalExpr(form.enabled,{ model: model, 'arrayIndex': arrayIndex }))" preselected="model['notifications']['preferredMedium']" options="form.titleMap" name="notifications.preferredMedium" style="">

 <div class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-description ng-binding" ng-bind="selectedDescription || 'Select'">Select</div>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu" autofocus="autofocus">

      <li class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option" data-value="select-all" data-role="option" ng-click="selectAll()">Check All</li>

      <li class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option" data-value="unselect-all" data-role="option" ng-click="deselectAll();">Uncheck All</li>

      <li class="divider"/>

      <li class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option ng-binding ng-scope" ng-attr-data-checked="{{isChecked(option.value) ? 1 : 0}}" data-type="value" ng-attr-data-value="{{::option.value}}" data-role="option" ng-class="{selected: keyBoardPointer(option.value)}" ng-click="setSelectedItem(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" data-checked="0" data-value="email"> Email </li>

      <li class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option ng-binding ng-scope" ng-attr-data-checked="{{isChecked(option.value) ? 1 : 0}}" data-type="value" ng-attr-data-value="{{::option.value}}" data-role="option" ng-class="{selected: keyBoardPointer(option.value)}" ng-click="setSelectedItem(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" data-checked="0" data-value="mobileNo"> SMS </li>

      <li class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option ng-binding ng-scope" ng-attr-data-checked="{{isChecked(option.value) ? 1 : 0}}" data-type="value" ng-attr-data-value="{{::option.value}}" data-role="option" ng-class="{selected: keyBoardPointer(option.value)}" ng-click="setSelectedItem(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" data-checked="0" data-value="phoneNo"> Phone </li>

      <li class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-option ng-binding ng-scope" ng-attr-data-checked="{{isChecked(option.value) ? 1 : 0}}" data-type="value" ng-attr-data-value="{{::option.value}}" data-role="option" ng-class="{selected: keyBoardPointer(option.value)}" ng-click="setSelectedItem(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" data-checked="0" data-value="fax"> Fax </li>

  </ul>
```

I created the element as below:

```
      @FindBy(css="div[name='notifications.preferredMedium']")
      private WebElement  profPrefMedium;
```

The error coming is as below: "Element is not clickable at point (1172.199951171875, 642.2999877929688).
Other element would receive the click:  ".

Any one can help on this.

Comment: you need to provide us with the actual HTML

Comment: there are many ways that could have caused this, for examples, the element you tried to click has change its physical location from the last time you inspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Finally, I got answer.  
It worked with javascriptExecutor.  
 `jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",profPrefMedium);`  

Thanks all for your help in solving my problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try using Explicit wait with Expeceted condition as

```
WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement buttonToClick = myWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("yourelementid")));
if (buttonToClick != null) buttonToClick.Click();
```

Comment: I tried this option, execution went inside the if loop and then i got , element not clickable error again.

Comment: following function will be called to click on the dropdown.                     

 `public void selectPreferredMedium() throws Exception
     {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(profPrefMedium));
    
     profPrefMedium.click();
            
     }`

Comment: Are you able to click on the element manually.I suspect clicking on 'profPrefMedium' is not working.May be you can give a try to find the '<div class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-description ng-binding" ng-bind="selectedDescription || 'Select'">Select</div>' and then try to click on it.

Comment: i have tried to find the element <Select> by giving the xpath as below   `@FindBy(xpath="div[name='notifications.preferredMedium']/div")      
      private WebElement  profPrefMedium;`    still I got the same issue.   In manual execution i am able to click the field and select the value.

Comment: Oh.. You are able to find the select but not able to click on it.Am i correct?

Comment: Then try to find the UL tag and try to click on it.Sorry for too many suggestions.But this is how i work when things doesn't go as expected

Comment: i observed one thing now, this preferredMedium element is little bit down in the screen, in that screen, if i scroll manually, that time it is clicking on that drop down. So, how to solve this issue. please help

Comment: Then you may have to move the focus to the element either by using MouseActions or by writing a customized method to scrollandclick

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035023/selenium-webdriver-cant-click-on-a-link-outside-the-page see this link for scrollandclick method

Comment: i am not understanding the reason either javaScriptExecutor to scroll down or mouse actions or the customized method are not worked. when i manually move down only script is working.

Comment: Did you try Scroll and Click method? Is so you can have a customized method which witll scroll down.Please google.

Comment: Here is the code for scroll. IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("scroll(0,500);");

Answer (score -1):

Please try to `MovetoElement(Actions)` and then perform the `click()`

Perhaps this will help you to work around the issue

Code should be formatted as above, as per the guidelines.